# how to load active html in webview

Tags: javascript, android, html

I dont know how to ask this really. I have a html file and a js file that is htlms course. I want to show the html in web view in android and in that page user must do some calculation.
I saved the html file in pc it works and calculate stuff but in phone doesn't work, I put my layout and class code below.

I hope that makes sense. I want to load html file and src (js) file which is htmls course together.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webcalc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webcalc);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/calc.html");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work" ? Where in your assets did you put your HTML file ? Try to enable JavaScript for your WebView (with `wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`) also try to embed your JavaScript in your HTML instead of having it as a separate file.

Comment: should i put my src(js) file address in html file?

Comment: Put your js and css as inline code. And yes enableJavascript for your WebView

Comment: Try to put your actual script itself in your HTML file like `<script type="text/javascript"> your script here </script>` instead of as a separate .is file.

Comment: thanks all.it workded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

love u guys i enabled java and i put src addres into html file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/calculator.js"></script>
```

js was encrypted :)